# Multiple threads re-locking mutex

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads, mutex

I was wondering what happens when mutex unlocks, and two different threads waiting for that same mutex receive acknowledgement of that? Is there some queue like order to assign mutex to a thread that requested it first or is the choice random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html):

> If there are threads blocked on the mutex object referenced by mutex when pthread_mutex_unlock() is called, resulting in the mutex becoming available, the scheduling policy shall determine which thread shall acquire the mutex.

So the choice can be random, it can be a queue, it can be whatever the scheduler wishes to do.

Comment: And by scheduler, would that be the kernel scheduler?

Comment: Yes, it would be the operating system's scheduler.

Comment: *Typically* it is the operating system's scheduler, but it does not have to be.  A pthreads implementation can be written entirely in userspace, without relying on the OS scheduler.